# Differentiating between root and calling module providers in Terraform 0.11

Tags: terraform

I have a Terraform module (let's call it `module1`) that utilizes a `google` and `google-beta` provider of version `2.20`.

I intend to call this module from another one (let's call it `module2`) that (for some reason) has a restriction on the `google` and `google-beta` providers' configuration, as follows:

```
provider "google-beta" {
  version = "< 2.12"
}

provider "google" {
  version = "< 2.12"
}
```

Is there a way to make `module2` instantiate `module1` (more or less as follows) and keep its providers' restriction?

(let's assume the below snippet is from `main.tf` of `module2`

```
module mymodule {
  source        = "../../../path/to/module1"
}

provider "google-beta" {
  version = "< 2.12"
}

provider "google" {
  version = "< 2.12"
}
```

...while at the same time, `module1` gets to keep its own version of `google` providers?

Answer (score 0):

You can [pass providers explicitly when calling modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/modules.html#passing-providers-explicitly)

In `module2` define 2 more providers with aliases and appropriate versions, then call `module1` using those providers explicitly

```
module mymodule {
  source        = "../../../path/to/module1"

  providers = {
    google-beta = "google-beta.newer"
    google      = "google.newer"
  }
}

provider "google-beta" {
  version = "< 2.12"
}

provider "google" {
  version = "< 2.12"
}

provider "google-beta" {
  version = "~> 2.20"
  alias   = "newer"
}

provider "google" {
  version = "~> 2.20"
  alias   = "newer"
}
```

Comment: This fails due to the following `No provider "google-beta" plugins meet the constraint "< 2.12,~> 2.20,~> 2.20".`

Comment: Don't know why it would give you that error, especially when we're using pseudo code, did you define empty provider blocks in `module1`? The last paragraph of the section of docs I linked to mentions some requirements for terraform 0.11 around needing an empty provider block in child modules when passing explicitly